# Compiling simple token identifier using flex

Tags: gcc, compilation, flex-lexer

I have a basic lex file:

```
%{

/* Declarations section */
#include <stdio.h>
void showToken(char *);

%}

%option yylineno
%option noyywrap
digit           ([0-9])
whitespace      ([\t\n ])

%%

{digit}+                    showToken("number");
{whitespace}                ;
.       printf("Lex doesn't know what that is!\n");

%%

void showToken(char * name)
{
     printf("Lex found: %s, %s", name, yytext);
}
```

I've installed gcc and flex.
I compile the following commands:

```
flex example.lex
gcc -ll lex.yy.c
```

but i get the error:

```
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to explictly write "gcc -L"C:\GnuWin32\lib" -lfl lex.yy.c".

Answer (score 2):

To use the flex library you need to provide `-lfl` instead of `-ll`.

```
flex example.lex
gcc -lfl lex.yy.c
```

`-ll` only works if you're using the original lex command and its library. cygwin contains only flex, the free gnu version.

Comment: thank you, but it still writes the same error but with 'lfl'

Comment: You need the flex library. Is there a file `/usr/lib/libfl.a` on your system? It is part of the flex package (https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fflex%2Fflex-2.6.4-2&grep=flex).

Comment: I've installed with the default settings..which have installed it in C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32, and there is libfl.a file in the lib folder

Comment: The flex package on your cygwin installation is missing or inclompete. Just reinstall it: https://cygwin.com/install.html

Comment: reinstalled it and now I get "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../lib/libfl.a(libmain.o): In function `main':
/usr/src/debug/flex-2.6.4-0.1/src/libmain.c:33: undefined reference to `yylex'
/usr/src/debug/flex-2.6.4-0.1/src/libmain.c:33:(.text.startup+0x11): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `yylex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
"

Comment: The command `flex example.lex` should have generated the file `lex.yy.c`. `yylex` is the main scanner function inside lex.yy.c, disguised as `YY_DECL`. Please check if `lex.yy.c` contains `YY_DECL`.